# xpath - sometimes its working and sometimes not

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

Below is my xpath for the element "Payment options" .

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//parent//a[contains(text(),'Payment Options')]")).click();
```

Its giving an error saying it cannot find the xpath. But it was working when i initially created the script. I have tried with Css selector too but failed. (copying the css selector)
[image]

Comment: Can you check with By.partialLinkText method or By.linkText method ?

Comment: driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Payment Options")).click();

Comment: Have you tried a wait? The page may be loading slowly at times which is causing a failure. There are many locators you could use... you could try linkText but it's hard to tell if there is whitespace in the A tag. You could try partialLinkText to get around that. You could use a CSS selector `a[href=/billing/payment-options"]`, etc.

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.